# React Component won't render after Jquery Ajax Call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, reactjs

I have a simple jquery ajax that fetch inline HTML code from an API

```
$.ajax({
  url:      url,
  headers:  { 'Accept': 'application/javascript' },
  dataType: 'html',
  beforeSend: function(){
    $('.load-more').slideDownThenFadeIn(100);
  }
})
.done(function(data) {
  $('#container').append(data);
});
```

It's a simple button not built with React

```
<a class="btn load-more" href="javascript:void(0)">Load More</a>
```

The Ajax call invokes the API to render html code back to the server...

It renders back the html code below

```
<div data-react-class=\"My.React.Base.PostButton\" data-react-props=\"{&quot;buttonText&quot;:&quot;Contact me&quot;,&quot;buttonClass&quot;:&quot;btn btn-clear btn-block&quot;,&quot;business&quot;:{&quot;id&quot;:86055,&quot;business_name&quot;:&quot;Buy Plan&quot;,&quot;mobile_phone&quot;:&quot;0412 345 678&quot;},&quot;cta&quot;:&quot;card&quot;,&quot;slideTitle&quot;:null,&quot;showPostJobExclusively&quot;:true,&quot;showToAll&quot;:false,&quot;CallCustomer&quot;:false}\"></div>
```

but react component did not render...

I'm actually expecting the react component to be rendered, but below is missing after appending the ajax data

```
<a data-reactroot="" class="btn btn-clear btn-block" href="#"><span><!-- react-text: 3 -->Contact me<!-- /react-text --></span></a>
```

Am I missing something here?

EDIT:

```
<div class="card"><div class="col-xs-6 pr8"><div data-react-class="SS.React.Base.ProfileJobPostButton" data-react-props="{&quot;buttonText&quot;:&quot;Contact me&quot;,&quot;buttonClass&quot;:&quot;btn btn-clear btn-block&quot;,&quot;business&quot;:{&quot;id&quot;:129679,&quot;business_name&quot;:&quot;IMC Cleaning Services&quot;,&quot;mobile_phone&quot;:&quot;6197877882&quot;},&quot;cta&quot;:&quot;business_directory_card&quot;,&quot;slideTitle&quot;:null,&quot;showPostJobExclusively&quot;:true,&quot;showPostJobToAll&quot;:false,&quot;showCallBusiness&quot;:false}"></div></div>
```

the React component from API looks something like below

```
render() {
  return(
    <a className={this.props.buttonClass} href="#" onClick={this.handleOnClick}>
      {
        this.state.loading ?
          <My.React.Base.Spinner spinnerColour='white-spinner' />
        :
        <span>
          {this.props.buttonText}
          {this.props.withArrow && <i className="ficon-arrow-right-shaft pl10" />}
        </span>
      }
    </a>
  )
}
```

Comment: Can you also provide your root html file(index.html may be). I just wanna know the container. How do you render container

Comment: @Aditya updated the post... should just simply render a link, but upon inspecting on browser... the link is missing... I can only see the `<div data-react-class` snippet code.

Comment: Is there a reason why react component didn't render after the Jquery Ajax append? Do I need the ajax request to be in react as well or doesn't matter? I'm new to React and I would like to know when components render? I've tried to set a timeout on append data... thinking that there's just a race condition but didn't work too. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You are using a wrong approach. First of all you should not force render html code inside the react components. so usually APIs should return data and html should be the part of react component.

But anyways if you are using this approach you should use **dangerouslySetInnerHtml** attribute of react  refer the link https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html

Thats the react way of modifying dom or appending html to dom nodes' html.

Also you can modify the component after the component is mounted. So if you are making API call after your component has mounted which usually is the case, you can store the html in state, and using the aforesaid attribute dangerouslySetInnerHTML, you can set its value to state variable.